# PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 impact of key length to the output length

Tags: java, cryptography, sha, pbkdf2

Consider the following java code:

```
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec("pass".toCharArray(), "salt".getBytes(),
    10000, 512);
SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
System.out.println(f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded().length);
```

This code outputs "`64`". So 64 bytes, while SHA-256 is a 32 byte hash.

I know I specified 512 bits (64 byte) as the key length.
However I would **expect** that the generated key
(PBKDF2) will be hashed by SHA-256 so that the **output should always be 32 bytes, irrespective what key size I am using.**

What I am missing (or why are my expectations wrong)?

Comment: A main feature of [PBKDF2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2898#section-5.2), especially versus its predecessor now retronymed PBKDF1, is that its output can be almost any size and in particular larger than an output from the underlying hash.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I agree. But I've chosen the PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 variant so I would expect I always get an SHA256 (32 bytes) from the output. This seems to be not the case. Why?

Comment: @MRalwasser: You say you agree, but you ignored "... and in particular **larger than an output from the underlying hash**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write PBKDF as `DK = PBKDF2(PRF, Password, Salt, c, dkLen)`

- `PRF` is pseudorandom function with output length `hlen`
- `dkLen` is the desired bit-length of the derived key
- 'c' is the number of iterations

How it is calculated;

```
DK = T1 ‖ T2 ‖ ... ‖ T_{dklen/hlen}
```

Where `Ti = F(Password, Salt, c, i)` and each has `hlen` sizes.

```
F(Password, Salt, c, i) = U1 ⊕ U2 ⊕ ... ⊕ Uc
```

and

```
U1 = PRF(Password, Salt + INT_32_BE(i))
U2 = PRF(Password, U1)
...
Uc = PRF(Password, Uc-1)
```

The `dklen` can be at most 2^32 - 1 times the size of the output of the backend hash (PRF).

as you can see, with little modification of the salt with 32-bit encoded value of `i`, PBKDF2 can output multiple `hlen` outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but I am missing the SHA256 part in your answer which is the crucial component in my question. Following your functional definition, it looks that PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 can be written as a function of SHA256(PBKDF2(..)). Is this true and if so, why is the output length not always 256 bit?

Comment: It means that it uses `HmacSHA256` and the `hlen` bit size is 32 bytes. Now, if you ask more than that, `dkLen` the PBKDF2 will generate T2, T3,.. to produce keys for the desired length upto `2^32 - 1 * hLen`

Comment: So PRF is in my case SHA256?

Comment: HMACSHA256 is your PRF. HMAC uses SHA256.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that the HMACSHA256 function is in fact an input argument of PBKDF2. I thought that it processes the outpuf of PBKDF2. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote a generic answer so that one can replace the PRF with the choice to figure out the `hLen`