# Cipher only encrypts one file in the directory

Tags: java, encryption, aes-gcm

I am writing a program that encrypts and decrypts a directory of files and replaces them with the ciphered files. So far, the program works when there is a single file in the directory, but past that, it will not encrypt anything else. The program complains that the same key or iv is being used, but we want to use the same cipher for the encryption of all the files in the directory, and Cipher.dofinal should reset the cipher back to the initial state, according to the documentation. There is other code pertaining to the creation of the AES key, and etc. but that seems to be working fine. Does anyone have any ideas what is causing this problem?

```
      //Creates Cipher and encodes with the AES key
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, AESKey, spec);
      //write all files to directory
      File dir = new File(directory);
      if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        EncryptDirectory(dir, cipher);
      } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Directory Invalid");
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  static public void EncryptDirectory(File dir, Cipher cipher) throws Exception {
    String[] pathnames;
    pathnames = dir.list();
    for (String pathname : pathnames) {
      File dirFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+ pathname);
      if (dirFile.isDirectory()) {
        EncryptDirectory(dirFile, cipher);
      } else if (pathname.equals("keyfile") || pathname.equals("keyfile.sig")) {
        continue;
      } else {
        String newFile = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + dirFile.getName() + ".ci"; // Not sure what this will be.
        // Error checking if file exists
        File newFileCreate = new File(newFile);
        if (!newFileCreate.createNewFile()) {
          newFileCreate.delete();
          newFileCreate.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream cipherFile = new FileOutputStream(newFileCreate);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+ pathname);
        byte[] ibuf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(ibuf)) != -1) {
          byte[] obuf = cipher.update(ibuf, 0, len);
          if ( obuf != null ) {
            cipherFile.write(obuf);
          }
        }
        cipherFile.write(cipher.doFinal());
        cipherFile.close();
        in.close();
        if (!dirFile.delete()) {
          System.out.println("Error in deleting file.");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Multiple use of the same key/IV pair is generally insecure. This is particularly dramatic in the context of GCM, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26790). Apparently `Cipher` checks this (to some extent) and displays, quite correctly, an error message. So you have to change your architecture for security reasons. If you want to use the same key, you would have to generate a random IV for each file. The IV is needed for decryption and is therefore usually contacted with the ciphertext.

Comment: If your key is derived from a password then you should use PBKDF2 (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58508998/238704) with **a fresh random salt for each file** to derive a file-unique key and iv/nonce. The salt should be attached to the ciphertext as @Topaco indicated. The decryptor must *first* extract the salt from the ciphertext and then derive the key and iv/nonce all over again to decrypt the file. If the password given to the decryptor is wrong then `cipher.doFinal()` with throw an exception because the GCM tag will fail to verify.